# eigen::vectorXf to MatriXf map

Tags: c++, eigen

In eigen c++, how do you 
map a vectorXf to a matrixXf 
(of appropriate dimensions)

(there is good [docs](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialMapClass.html) on 
how to do it for external objects 
so i know we can do:

`MatrixXf x_cen=Map<MatrixXf>(*x,*n,*p);`

but what if `x`is a `VectorXf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the .data() member function followed by Map:

```
VectorXf vec(rows*cols);
vec = ...;
Map<MatrixXf> vec_view_as_a_matrix(vec.data(), rows, cols);
```

Then you can use vec_view_as_a_matrix just like any Eigen objects, modifications to vec_view_as_a_matrix will be reported to vec as well since they are sharing the memory. If you want to copy to a new MatrixXf object, then use the construction you wrote:

```
MatrixXf x_cen = Map<MatrixXf>(vec.data(), rows, cols);
```