# map eigen::MatrixXf to an existing eigen::matrixXf

Tags: c++, eigen

Sometime [ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395431/eigenvectorxf-to-matrixf-map) user ggael gave an answer to the 
problem of mapping a eigen::vectorXf to an eigen::matrixXf.

Now, i need to do something similar, but to an existing matrix, 
e.g i know i can:

```
for(int i=0;i<p;++i){
    VectorXf vec=q.col(i);
    /*q is a p**2 by n matrix*/ 
    Map<MatrixXf> qi(vec.data(),p,p);
    /*run function that uses qi to produce a scalare and store that scalar*/
}
```

but (it seems to me) it would be more efficient to 
create `qi` once and for all outside the loop and then 
use the same `qi` over and over again (is that right?)

Also, i wonder whether the intermediate step where 
i map `q.col(i)` to `vec` is really necessary...

A recent answer [proposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003692/mapping-array-back-to-an-existing-eigen-matrix) to do:

```
qi=Map<MatrixXd>(vec.data(),p,p);
```

but doing that yields:

```
In function ‘Eigen::VectorXi DepType(const MatrixXf&, const MatrixXf&, const int&)’:
DeC.cpp:279:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001> >::Map(Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, 1> >::Scalar*, int&, int&)’
DeC.cpp:279:34: note: candidates are:
/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Map.h:179:12: note: Eigen::Map<MatrixType, MapOptions, StrideType>::Map(Eigen::Map<MatrixType, MapOptions, StrideType>::PointerArgType, Eigen::Map<MatrixType, MapOptions, StrideType>::Index, Eigen::Map<MatrixType, MapOptions, StrideType>::Index, const StrideType&) [with PlainObjectType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>, int MapOptions = 0, StrideType = Eigen::Stride<0, 0>, Eigen::Map<MatrixType, MapOptions, StrideType>::PointerArgType = double*, Eigen::Map<MatrixType, MapOptions, StrideType>::Index = long int]
/home/kaveh/Desktop/work/p1/geqw4/vi3/out/sp/ccode/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Map.h:179:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, 1> >::Scalar* {aka float*}’ to ‘double*’
/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Map.h:166:12: note: Eigen::Map<MatrixType, MapOptions, StrideType>::Map(Eigen::Map<MatrixType, MapOptions, StrideType>::PointerArgType, Eigen::Map<MatrixType, MapOptions, StrideType>::Index, const StrideType&) [with PlainObjectType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>, int MapOptions = 0, StrideType = Eigen::Stride<0, 0>, Eigen::Map<MatrixType, MapOptions, StrideType>::PointerArgType = double*, Eigen::Map<MatrixType, MapOptions, StrideType>::Index = long int]
/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Map.h:166:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, 1> >::Scalar* {aka float*}’ to ‘double*’
/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Map.h:154:12: note: Eigen::Map<MatrixType, MapOptions, StrideType>::Map(Eigen::Map<MatrixType, MapOptions, StrideType>::PointerArgType, const StrideType&) [with PlainObjectType = Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>, int MapOptions = 0, StrideType = Eigen::Stride<0, 0>, Eigen::Map<MatrixType, MapOptions, StrideType>::PointerArgType = double*]
/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Map.h:154:12: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Map.h:119:79: note: Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001> >::Map(const Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001> >&)
/eigen/Eigen/src/Core/Map.h:119:79: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
```

e.g. it seems Eigen thinks `qi` is a [vector](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialMapClass.html#TutorialMapTypes)....:(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following:

```
qi=Map<MatrixXd>(vec.data(),p,p);
```

means that you want to copy the coefficients of Map(vec.data(),p,p) into the matrix referenced by qi. However, what you actually want is to re-initialize the Map<> object. To do so you must call the constructor again using the construct new syntax of C++:

```
new (&qi) Map<MatrixXd>(vec.data(),p,p);
```

Moreover, I must say that a Map<> object is extremely lightweight: it is only one pointer and 2 integers that are statically allocated on the stack. So moving the declaration of Map<> qi outside the loop will have zero effect on the performance. On the other hand, note that you do not need to copy q.col(i) into a temporary buffer. If q is column major, you can directly do:

```
Map<MatrixXf> qi(q.col(i).data(),p,p);
```

Comment: thanks ggael! (specially for the advice to leave the qi inside the loop).

Comment: Also, i had tried the construction you suggested and was getting an error message. Now, i realize that it was because q was declared as a const MatrixXf (apparently for this to work, q has to be a MatrixXf)

Comment: if q is const, then use: Map<const MatrixXf>

Comment: Thanks, i'd rather leave q as const!