# workaround for Eigen::Matrix to release data

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I want to use Eigen3 on data coming from another library. An earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264413/map-eigenmatrixxf-to-an-existing-eigenmatrixxf) by ggael indicates a way for `Eigen::Matrix` to adopt preexsisting data with the `new` keyword. However, this is not sufficient for me, because the resulting `Matrix` still seems to acquire ownership of the data, meaning that it will free the data when going out of scope. To wit, this is a crasher if `data` eventually gets deleted by the library it comes from:

```
void crasher(double* data, size_t dim)
{
  MatrixXd m;

  new (&m) Map<MatrixXd>(data,dim,dim); // matrix adopts the passed data
  m.setRandom(); cout<<m<<endl; // manipulation of the passed data via the Matrix interface
} // data deleted by m => potential problem in scope of function call
```

I have come up with two workarounds:

```
void nonCrasher1(double* data, size_t dim)
{
  MatrixXd m; // semantically, a non-owning matrix
  const Map<const MatrixXd> cache(m.data(),0,0); // cache the original „data” (in a const-correct way)

  new (&m) Map<MatrixXd>(data,dim,dim); // matrix adopts the passed data
  m.setRandom(); cout<<m<<endl; // manipulation of the passed data via the Matrix interface

  new (&m) Map<const MatrixXd>(cache); // re-adopting the original data
} // original data deleted by m
```

This is rather inconvenient because of the presence of `cache`. The other is free from this problem:

```
void nonCrasher2(double* data, size_t dim) // no need for caching
{
  MatrixXd m; // semantically, a non-owning matrix

  new (&m) Map<MatrixXd>(data,dim,dim); // matrix adopts the passed data
  m.setRandom(); cout<<m<<endl; // manipulation of the passed data via the Matrix interface

  new (&m) Map<MatrixXd>(nullptr,0,0); // adopting nullptr for subsequent deletion
} // nullptr „deleted” by m (what happens with original data [if any]?)
```

However, here it’s unclear what happens with the original data of `m` (if any – all this is not completely clear from the documentation of Eigen3).

My question is whether there is a canonical way for `Eigen::Matrix` to release ownership of it’s data (self-allocated or adopted).

Comment: I am also trying to find a way for Eigen::Matrix to release ownership of it’s data (self-allocated or adopted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `nonCrasher2` nothing happen to data, except that it has been filled with random values on purpose.

However, this still look like hackish, and the clean approach be to use a `Map` object instead of `MatrixXd`:

```
Map<MatrixXd> m(data, dim, dim);
m.setRandom();
```

If you need `m` to be a `MatrixXd` because you need to call functions taking `MatrixXd` objects, and such functions cannot be templated, then you might consider generalizing these functions to take `Ref<MatrixXd>` objects. By default, a `Ref<MatrixXd>` can accept any expression which storage reassemble to a `MatrixXd` with arbitrary leading dimension. It has been introduced in Eigen 3.2, check the doc for more details.

Comment: In `nonCrasher2` I mean the data of the matrix `m`: what is the data of a default-initialized matrix? Indeed I need `m` to be a `MatrixXd` because actually I want to calculate eigenvalues, and the `Eigen::…EigenSolver` templates do not accept `Map` types. Can they be used with `Ref`?

Comment: By default it is a null pointer. You can still do `EigenSolver<MatrixXd> eig(Map<MatrixXd>(data,dim,dim))` with one extra copy. Negligible compared to the cost of the eigen value decomposition. But you're right, EigenSolver<MatrixXd> should accept Map/Block/Ref, etc.

Comment: Indeed that would be pretty nice. I hope from now on, it’s on the to-do list ;)